# Access content of a cell using the row id and class of that cell - jquery

Tags: jquery

In my html table .. I know the row id (eg : testRow01) . Using this id i want to get content of a cell in that row. I know the class of that cell(eg: startTime) .How can i do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### jQuery

```
var content = $('#testRow01 .startTime').html();
```

#### JavaScript

Just for the hell of it, here is how you would do it without jQuery...

```
var content = document.getElementById('testRow01')
               .getElementsByClassName('startTime')[0]
               .innerHTML;
```

...and if you didn't have `getElementsByClassName()`...

```
var tds = document.getElementById('testRow01').getElementsByTagName('td');

for (var i = 0, tdsLength = tds.length; i < tdsLength; i++) {
   var td = tds[i];
   if (td.className.match(/\bstartTime\b/)) {
       var content = td.innerHTML;
       break;
   }
}
```